# I cannot find a space between strings

Tags: regex

I have an input:

```
0603534121 SPRUILL JAMES  2814 BRONX  BRONX   NY104670000 12/31/0112/28/0112/28/01
```

I need regular expression to find the third space between JAMES and 2814 that remove it from output file, also between BRONX and BRONX.

Comment: Rather than explaining a single example, could you give the rule you're going for? Like, when do you want to remove spaces and when don't you?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to remove the 3rd and 5th space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it using:

```
^([^ ]* [^ ]* [^ ]*) ([^ ]* [^ ]*) (.*)$
```

after matching this you just have to put the 3 matched groups together.